# What email header fields can have parameters?

Tags: email, mime, email-headers

I am trying to find out what universal subroutines can I have in an email parsing library.

I know of two MIME fields that often take parameters:

```
Content-Type: application/x-stuff;
 title*=us-ascii'en-us'This%20is%20%2A%2A%2Afun%2A%2A%2A
```

(example from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231)

and

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=genome.jpeg;
 modification-date="Wed, 12 Feb 1997 16:29:51 -0500";
```

(example from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183)

Are they the only ones - or is this an universal mechanism?  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822 only talks about 'structured' fields - the fields above are 'structured' for sure, but the example in rfc822 is about an address field - which is a different structure - *list* of addresses.

Comment: Your terminology is not very precise. To my knowledge there are no other headers in common use with the `Field: value-type/subtype; type-specific-attribute=something` look, but it is not at all clear if this is what you are after. Please clarify. What does "parameter" mean to you in this context? What do you need the answer for?

Comment: A one sentence clarification added at the beginning of the post.  Ad 'parameters' - this is what the RFC 2231 talks about - part of the question is what that really means.

Answer (score 1):

There are two more MIME fields in email as far as I know:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

which has no parameters, and

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: ...
```

has none, either.

There is no general "MIME header field parameter rule", just look up the standard definition for each header field.

(EDIT:) After your additions to the original question, you can of course use universal subroutines. Be warned that email heaader parsing is a nontrivial task (cf. RFC 2822). These universal subroutines come into my mind:

- Remove comments in the header fields (denoted by parenthesis).
- Handle tab indent lines (continuation lines)
- Parse RFC822 date/times (huge task :)
- Handle quotation
- Parse email addresses (different forms)
- Handle character encoding (MIME header encoding)

However, all this exists in many open source libraries of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'll see what others say - but for now I'll change the title :)

Comment: Sure I am using a library (Courriel in Perl) - it just failed for one of the cases of emails we receive and I am now trying to write an intelligent bug report/patch :)

Answer (score 1):

The Received: header is typically structured, although the spec is rather vague and there is no serious standardization effort. The closest thing resembling a de facto standard is Sendmail, which is mimicked more or less closely by Postfix. The DKIM signature is structured, in a fairly clever way. The ad hoc header inserted by SpamAssassin has a structure; it tells you why a message was classified as spam. There are oodles more, but this should give you something to start chewing. None of the examples here use the Mime Content-xxx syntax.

Comment: The received: header field *is* standardized in RFC 2882, but quite loosely.

Comment: Erm uh, come again, do you mean section 3.6.7 of RFC5382? 2882 is about RADIUS authentication.

Comment: I meant RFC 28*2*2, "Internet Message Format", section 3.6.7, sorry. What do you mean by RFC 5382, "NAT Behavioral Requirements for TCP", which has no section 3.6.7? :)

Comment: oh well, I see the newer RFC 5322 further loosens the syntax of "Received:". We even no longer need key/value pairs. Still, the semicolon and the timestamp must be in place.

Comment: So much for communicating via RFC numbers (-: Yes I mean 5322 "of course" ... Should have realized you meant 2822, obviously, sorry about that.